# Why do I have 2 httpd module folders? /usr/lib64/httpd/modules and /etc/httpd/modules

Tags: apache-2.2, centos, centos6, httpd

I'm trying to compile mod_wsgi on Python 2.7 (which is not my server default) for my virtualenv.

I'm doing something like this:

```
wget -q "https://github.com/GrahamDumpleton/mod_wsgi/archive/4.2.8.tar.gz"
tar -xzf '4.2.8.tar.gz'
cd ./mod_wsgi-4.2.8
./configure --with-python=python2.7 --with-apxs=/usr/sbin/apxs LDFLAGS="-R/usr/local/lib" --prefix=/usr/local
make
make install
```

I have mod_wsgi.so at both `/usr/lib64/httpd/modules/mod_wsgi.so` and `/etc/httpd/modules/mod_wsgi.so`

In httpd.conf I have tried both of these:

```
LoadModule wsgi_module /usr/lib64/httpd/modules/mod_wsgi.so
LoadModule wsgi_module modules/mod_wsgi.so
```

Comment: Version 4.2.8 of mod_wsgi is old. The latest at this time is 4.4.13. Why use the old version?https://github.com/GrahamDumpleton/mod_wsgi/releases

Answer (score 2):

As @ikrabbe guesses, they are symlinked.

```
# ls -las /etc/httpd
total 16
4 drwxr-xr-x  4 root root 4096 Jun 19 12:43 .
4 drwxr-xr-x 50 root root 4096 Jun 19 12:43 ..
4 drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Jun 19 12:43 conf
4 drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Jun 19 12:43 conf.d
0 lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root   19 Jun 19 12:43 logs -> ../../var/log/httpd
0 lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root   29 Jun 19 12:43 modules -> ../../usr/lib64/httpd/modules
0 lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root   19 Jun 19 12:43 run -> ../../var/run/httpd
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm just guessing: /etc/httpd/modules links to /usr/lib64/httpd/modules, so both are the same files.